# Flink jdbc SSL connection support

Tags: jdbc, apache-flink

I am using Flink JDBC connector for connecting to postgreSQL database. Everything seems work fine. Until now we are using username/password method to establish connection. Just wanted check if it supports SSL based connectivity.
Thanks